# remove remember me check box from asp:login control

Tags: asp.net, authentication, checkbox

I want to create a login with ASP.NET 4 but without `rememberMe` check box. Is any way to do this?

Comment: You can use the Jquery to hide the rememberMe check box.

Comment: @MaheshAlle This is non-ideal as it only hides the problem, meaning that -eg- someone without JS or anyone with a little html knowledge will be able to see/use the checkbox

Comment: Just try this <asp:Login DisplayRememberMe="False" />

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.displayrememberme%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If you are using that control, you just need to put something like below in your aspx file:

```
<asp:Login DisplayRememberMe="False" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Press the drop down menu and press `Convert To Template`. And then just delete it.
In addition, there is a property which is `DisplayRememberMe` you can just put it false.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this just by using property of login control to control the display of `RememberMe`

for that you  have to set that property equals to false

```
 <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DisplayRememberMe="false">
        </asp:Login>
```

or you can also convert this into template and can remove whatever items you don't want to use.  by default template control look like this . you can remove remember me from this HTML .

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DisplayRememberMe="false">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                        Log In</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                            ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                            ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                            ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                            ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" 
                                            ValidationGroup="Login1" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:Login>
```